# Perfect cover equivalent of the 57-cell?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

The [Perkel graph](https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/graphs/Perkel.html) or 57-cell has the 57 vertices $Z_3 \times Z_{19}$ and 171 edges.

The perfect covering [C(19,3,2)](https://www.ccrwest.org/cover/t_pages/t2/k3/C_19_3_2.html) has 57 triplets which cover the 171 2-subsets of {1,2,...,18,19}. There are at least $19!$
 variations of the given covering.

Is there a covering that leads directly to the Perkel graph?

Comment: Not an answer, but, the automorphism group of the Perkel graph is PSL(2,19) which does not have a permutation representation on 19 points. So my guess is no.